# Transistor pin configuration

Tags: voltage, transistors, power, amperage, biasing

Is the base of a transistor (NPN) always positive or does it change due to manufacturers specs; as some might decide to put the base as pin 1 , followed by the rest; maybe collector as pin 2 etc like it's done on the TIP120[image: tip120]

Comment: `always positive` ... positive relative to what? ... what does pin 1 have to do with the polarity of the base?

Comment: Pin outs *always* require a datasheet. There is no universal pattern.

Comment: 'always positive ... positive relative to what?'... Relative to biasing the transistor as an amplifier

Comment: Polarity during use and mechanical pin assignments are different things. Please clarify.

Comment: Normally to bias a transistor you forward bias the base emmitter junction and reverse bias the collector junction right?... So with this pin arrangement how  am i certain wich pin is positive or negative?

Comment: @imranmuhd When you say reverse biasing the collector, you must state in reference to which terminal it would be reverse biased, with emitter or base?

Comment: @imranmuhd The base of an npn should always be positive relative to the emitter for typical amplifying operation, but whether the base is pin 1, 2, 3, or something else varies from transistor to transistor.

Answer (score 2):

There are no universal rules about pin assignments. Pin assignments vary from one model of transistor to another. The datasheet for that model of transistor will show how the pins are assigned.

When an NPN transistor operated in forward active mode (which is the case in 99.9% of all NPN transistors amplifier circuits) the base will be positive with respect to the emitter.